# What word answers this riddle of letters and numbers?

Tags: word

As you enter a clinic, you catch a whiff of a disgusting 2156. Oh, it must be that 351 that 123456 was eating for lunch. Eww, it's starting to 624, 425. Oh hey 16. Smith, didn't hear you come in. No, we didn't 4621 on your 324, it was already dirty when we came in. Oh, yes, we threw away your 351, it was starting to smell. Please, don't give us a 6524 canal, we didn't mean any harm. Here, we'll treat you 45 some delicious 4565 for dinner, how about it?

Comment: Just as an FYI, "No, we didn't 4621" is a grammatical error; it should be "we didn't 46ea1", since both "didn't and "4621" are past-tense and only "do" gets conjugated when you use a verb with do-support.  :-)

Comment: Never fear, suomynonA, the great grammar authority Bob Marley supports with your usage when ["46211ing on the wine press much too long" (0:56)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GCeJ_ldU70c)

Comment: @humn I feel much better now xD

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The word is

> DOCTOR. If you replace the letters 1-6 with the letters of DOCTOR, you get a coherent paragraph:
>
>  As you enter a clinic, you catch a whiff of a disgusting odor. Oh, it must be that cod that doctor was eating for lunch. Eww, it's starting to rot, too. Oh hey Dr. Smith, didn't hear you come in. No, we didn't trod on your cot, it was already dirty when we came in. Oh, yes, we threw away your cod, it was starting to smell. Please, don't give us a root canal, we didn't mean any harm. Here, we'll treat you to some delicious toro for dinner, how about it?

Comment: I knew this would get a quick answer, but wow. Did I give too many hints?

Comment: @suomynonA: Absolutely. I got it from 6524 and 16 - that was all that was necessary.

Comment: I'll try to make it harder next time... nice job

Answer (score 3):

Here is my answer.

> Lets start with "we'll treat you 45 some" 45 must mean to.
>  So 4 = t and 5 = o
>  6524 canal must be root canal so.
>  6 = r and 2 = o.
>  From there you can get that it's starting to 624, 425. is "it's starting to rot too."
>  2156 must be odor.  so 1 = d
>  123456 must be doctor. Which might be the word we are looking for since it has all the numbers in order.